# Object Caching using Laravel - Memcached

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.1

I would like to know the most efficient method/solution using relationships to return eloquent objects from a cache or the database.

For example:

I have a users table. Ideally I want to cache each user object individually using the key (User_$ID).

An User follows many User

```
User 1 followers: []
User 2 followers: [1] // User 1 follows User 2
User 3 followers: [1,2] // User 1 and User 2 follows the User 3
```

now if I call $user2->followers or $user3->followers, I will get a collection of eloquent user objects. If I store in cache each collection then User 1 is stored in both cache keys and thats not good as I will have data duplication in the cache. I would like to avoid this for several reasons but mainly because it helps maintain a well structured cache system that is easy to manage and clear. Other examples could include:

Product row with relational Store ID which matches stores table

$product::with('store')->get()
$store::find(1)

In this scenario the store would be saved in the cache under the product key and the store key again leading to duplication in data.

I could create a getByID function in my model to negate this but was wondering if anyone had solved this using Eloquent ?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, selecting from MySQL is always faster than using memcached and caching stuff there. Long story short, you'd benefit more if your code was simple and if it always pulled the data from the database. Not only is that faster, it's also easier to maintain. On the other hand, you might follow the mainstream and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You have to factor in processing time - converting these SQL rows to PHP objects, any formatting done on them etc not to mention that it is best to reduce concurrent connections to the DB ....

Comment: Great, you have some assumptions and now I can show you how they're wrong. `php-fpm` caches database connections, that's one of the reasons why we prefer serving php via `php-fpm` - connect once, use multiple times until the worker is killed. MySQL is advanced when it comes to caching (much like any SQL solution) and it's faster than memcached when it comes to accessing data in-memory. Your assumptions are valid, but sadly - wrong. It's quicker to select from the database all the time.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is absolutely no need to use memcached/redis etc because making sql calls will always be faster ?

Comment: That's correct, and that statement is only valid if php is properly configured, along with your database. If those are correctly set up, if your database has sufficient RAM to keep its dataset there then yes - making SQL calls will always be quicker than accessing redis or memcached. I'll just stress again - **if all the pieces are correctly set up**. What often happens is that people have a complex query and they cache its results in redis/memcached. It's much more efficient to materialize that data and let RDBMS worry about caching.

Comment: Okay brilliant thanks. So I should investigate serving php via php-fpm- any thing else I should be making sure of ?

Comment: It depends, like with many things. Start with using `php-fpm` and a light weight server (`nginx` should do the trick, but `apache` is able to do the job just fine). An SSD for database server would be ideal and sufficient RAM so the database can do its magic by eating up the RAM for its data (therefore, no need for memcached / redis).

Comment: In my experience, and the experience of many other articles available on the internet, N.B. is wrong about database being faster than caching, especially on a distributed stack (ie. database and web on different servers). The general consensus on performance, slowest to quickest is: DB > Remote Cache > Local Cache > PHP Cache.